# Firebug shows my js files in the net panel for a split second then they vanish

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to evaluate my js load times, but Firebug won't show them to me.

I go to the net panel, load the page, and I can see my 10 or 12 js files for a split second, but then they vanish and are replaced by Google Analytic's script as the only one that shows up at the end. What gives?

**EDIT:**

To illustrate what I'm experiencing, look at this series of screenshots. Though I took them about a minute apart, they represent about a 3 second period as if I were to count out loud 1, 2, 3, as I'm watching the page refresh and FB profile the js files being fetched. As you can see, it seems to at first see them all, then they just drop off. Even with persist enabled, the record only stores that one final file. Files: [One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrt8U.jpg), [Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpBJc.jpg), [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQlza.jpg).

**UPDATE**

If I go under the "ALL" tab it does display the other .js files, just not under the JS tab. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Javascript files are served with Content-Type `text/html` instead of `text/javascript`, `application/javascript` or `application/x-javascript`. Therefore they appear on HTML-Tab and not on JS-Tab as soon as Firebug has read the HTTP Header. Until Firebug has read the headers it seems like Firebug looks for the "extension" `*.js`. That's why you see your js-files for a moment in JS tab, but when the HTTP Header with wrong Content-Type is loaded they get switched over to the HTML-Tab.

**Summary**

You are sending wrong HTTP Content-Type `text/html` for JS-Files. Send proper HTTP Content-Type `application/javascript` for your JS-Files and everything should be fine.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks so much for shedding some light on this issue. How can I change the content-type? All of my links are of the  type="text/javascript" variety already.. could this be a server configuration issue? I have vague memories of playing with content types in order to gzip more of my content..

Comment: It is a server configuration issue. When your files are served directly from Apache then have a look at `mod_mime` documentation and the file `/etc/mime.types` on Debian systems. There is a content-type `application/javascript` configured for js-files on my system.

Comment: `application/javascript` should be the prefered content-type for javascript content. [IANA | MIME Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html)

Comment: I'm thinking this has to do with me adding this line to my .htaccess: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .js`. Couldn't figure out another way to get my php and js files to zip though.. hmm, unless there is another way around one of these issues, is there any practical reason to send the correct MIME type in this case since it is causing other benefits?

Comment: You should not do this. Use `mod_deflate` and something like `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml` in your configuration to serve these contents gzip'ed.

Comment: Based on mime type the client application decides how to handle the served content. The MIME type is very essential since without a given Content-Type the browser does not know what content to display, offer for download, how to display and so on ... It is only because mime declaration for js is redundant (HTTP header and inside HTML code) and the browser's fault-tolerance that your site works like it is.

Comment: Hmm, I'm told that mod_deflate isn't supported on the server.. looks like I'll need to start another post on this topic, don't want to get any further into it. Thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable `persist`, then the connections don't go away until you clear them manually.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.. I was really surprised when they vanished anyway.. I managed a screenshot in the second that they are there and you can see that the connection hasn't been made yet.. its as if it decides the files don't exist as soon as it makes the connection to them

Comment: Is this a Firefox only issue or does it exist in other browsers, too?

Comment: Does Firebug run on other browsers? I always assumed it was an FF only plugin.. I'll look into it

Comment: With Chrome, Opera and IE you have Developer Tools built in.

Comment: Ah, I see - where is the option in DT to monitor http request activity?

Comment: Basically all behave the same. Press F12. Go to the Network panel, in IE you have to press a capture button to start capturing.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't happen with IE, but the profiler seems quite different and it won't let me look at just js files.. it shows me all of the site files. Maybe I'm just not used to it.